# How to add gripper to UR5 arm?

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, gazebo, urdf

[image: UR_ARM]

I have UR5 arm without gripper I want to add gripper I have gripper urdf. Can anyone tell me how to add gripper what changes we need make in urdf ?

Comment: You only need a fixed joint between the end-effector link and the gripper link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also kind of new to ROS, but to my understanding, what you need to do is create a XACRO file where you import both the UR5 and the gripper URDF files, and then create a fixed joint between the last link of the UR5 and the base link on the gripper. I hope this helps :).